# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float' in custom made class

Tags: python, class, time, typeerror

I've made the following class to try and time a simulation I'm running: 
EDIT:

```
class TimeError(Exception):
"""A custom exception used to report errors in use of Timer Class"""
class simulation_timer: 
def __init__(self):
    self._simulation_start_time = None
    self._simulation_stop_time = None

def start(self):
    """start a new timer"""
    if self._simulation_start_time is not None:    # attribute
        raise TimeError(f"Timer is running.\n Use .stop() to stop it")

    self._simulation_start_time = time.perf_counter()  
def stop(self):
    """stop the time and report the elsaped time"""
    if self._simulation_start_time is None:
        raise TimeError(f"Timer is not running.\n Use .start() to start it.")

    self._simulation_stop_time = time.perf_counter
    elasped_simulation_time = self._simulation_stop_time - self._simulation_start_time  <-- Error here!
    self._simulation_start_time = None
    print(f"Elasped time: {elasped_simulation_time:0.4f} seconds")
```

and then I use it as follows in the below function:

```
def gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, popul_num_all, rxn_vector, tao, delta_t, epsi):
t = simulation_timer()
t.start()
while tao < tmax:
    propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)        
    a0 = (sum(propensity))
    if a0 == 0.0:
        break
    # if reaction cannot fire corresponding element in rxn_vector should be zero --> tau leaping method 
    if popul_num.any() < 0:
        break   
    lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t)
    rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam)    
    if tao + delta_t > tmax:
        break
    tao += delta_t
    print("tao:\n", tao)
    # divide tao by delta_t to calculate number of leaps
    leap_counter = tao / delta_t  # should this be after the if statement below? 
    if tao >= 2/a0:     
        for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):
            state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) 
            popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda
            new_propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)   # maybe inside for loop?  
        #for m in range(len(propensity)):
        for n in range(len(new_propensity)):
            propensity_check = propensity + state_change_lambda 
            if propensity_check[n] - new_propensity[n] >= epsi*a0:  
                print("The value of delta_t {} choosen is too large".format(delta_t))
                break
            else:
                popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda     
                popul_num_all.append(popul_num)   
                tao_all.append(tao)
                #return popul_num_all.append(popul_num), tao_all.append(tao), leap_counter
    else:
        t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
        rxn_probability = propensity / a0   
        num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
        if tao + t > tmax:      
            tao = tmax
            break
        j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs()
        tao = tao + t
        popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))   
        print("Simulation time:\n", t, tao)
t.stop()
return popul_num_all.append(popul_num), tao_all.append(tao), leap_counter
```

Only I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
```

I've looked up other posts on here that say it's something to do with redefining already builtin functions, so I've tried to rename all my variables but still no luck! Anyone have any ideas how I could fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Which line is throwing the error ?

Comment: Just edited showing where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to deduct float value from function:

```
elasped_simulation_time = time.perf_counter - self._simulation_start_time
```

perf_counter is a function represented in error by

> builtin_function_or_method

You can on start call it and save value, and do the same on stop, then deduct values.

Comment: I've tried editing my class to assign time.perf_counter to the stop call but I'm still getting the same error on the same line, any tips?

Comment: I solved it! I'd forgotten, the () at the end of:  self._simulation_stop_time = time.perf_counter()

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant by calling it, sorry for not being accurate enough :)